# How do I remove the style from grandparent and parent with only grandchild/child's id. (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to remove the styling of the grandparent then parent element of my child's id.
For example ~>

```html
    <div>
      <div>
        <div id='screenSelector'>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

However it returns an error in the console stating that `Cannot read property 'parentElement' of null`
How would I fix this issue?

Here is my current code ~>
*thank you in advance for all of your help and time.*

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        document.getElementById("screenSelector").parentElement.parentElement.removeAttribute("style");
        document.getElementById("screenSelector").parentElement.removeAttribute("style");
        document.getElementById("runButtonWrapper").parentElement.parentElement.removeAttribute("style");
        document.getElementById("runButtonWrapper").parentElement.removeAttribute("style");
        $("body").append(themeChangesCss);
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing native DOM selectors with the jQuery selector - the method to use in jQuery land is `.parent()` - I should also mention that it would be better to remove all inline styles anyway and rely on properly constructed CSS with correct styling and use of selectors.

Then the method to remove the attricture is `.removeAttr()` with the actual attribute listed.

For example- this code will work - in that it will remove the style attribute from the grandparent element of the selector- but there will be a flash of existing styling applied - before the jquery function works - remember the **document.ready** means that this will only be activated AFTER the loading of the DOM content - in this example a flash of red text before the style attribute is removed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
      // the following removes the color: red style attribute from the granparent element
      $("#screenSelector").parent().parent().removeAttr('style')
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div style="color: red;">
    GrandParent
    <div style="color: blue"> 
        Parent
      <div id='screenSelector' style="color: green">Child</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm really new to jQuery which is why I don't know much but I want to get into more advanced html and javascript so thank you I will use this knowledge no only now!